# Is it possible to filter vaadin accordion elements?

Tags: java, vaadin, accordion, vaadin14

I have 6 vaadin accordion components under each other, each one for specific kind of offers with 1000+ buttons (button per offer). Click on each button opens a new tab in another part of my layout. The accordions look like this:

```
        var firstDropDown = new Accordion();
        var firstDropDownContent = new VerticalLayout();
        firstDropDownContent.add(
                createButton("Offer1", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("Offer1", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
                createButton("Offer2", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("Offer2", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
                createButton("Offer3", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("Offer3", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
                createButton("Offer4", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("Offer4", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
                createButton("Offer5", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("Offer5", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
        firstDropDown.add("MarketingOffers", firstDropDownContent);
        firstDropDown.close();
        
        var secondDropDown = new Accordion();
        var secondDropDownContent = new VerticalLayout();
        secondDropDownContent.add(
                createButton("XOffer1", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("XOffer1", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
                createButton("XOffer2", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("XOffer2", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
                createButton("XOffer3", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("XOffer3", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
                createButton("XOffer4", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("XOffer4", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
                createButton("XOffer5", buttonClickEvent -> addNewTab("XOffer5", tabs, new VerticalLayout())),
        secondDropDown.add("OperationalOffers", secondDropDownContent);
        secondDropDown.close();
```

and so on...

Offers name are unique across the app (db constraint).

Now i want to add a text field above all the accordions in my layout that would act as a filter. When user types "1" i want to open, filter out and show him only those accordions button that contain "1". Is that kind of filtering/hiding other buttons possible with accordion component? If so then how can i achieve this?

I couldnt find any documentation about this.
I am using vaadin 14, java only (v11).

Comment: I have doubts that Accordion is the right component to use in your case. Is the number of tabs fixed to six, or can it be something else? You could also study possibility to use Grid and details renderer instead backed by data provider, which gives you filtering, better sync with data base, and possibility for multiple open tabs at the same time.

Comment: I need accordions to keep the GUI clean.
I will try to add grid with buttons instead of vertical layouts inside accordions, then in the filtering text field ill just add some logic for opening all accordions and filtering grids inside. i think this might work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this with

1. Adding Accordions that contain Grid with 1 column (buttons) instead of vertical layouts.
2. Adding data provider to grid
3. Adding this simple listener to search text field, that filters by the offer name which is also a button name in my case :)

   ```
    search.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
        if (event.getValue().isBlank()) {
            firstDropDown.close();
            secondDropDown.close();
            thirdDropDown.close();
            forthDropDown.close();
        } else {
            firstDropDown.open(0);
            secondDropDown.open(0);
            thirdDropDown.open(0);
            forthDropDown.open(0);
            offerFilterObject.setName(event.getValue());
        }
        dataProvider.refreshAll();
    })
   ```

This basically opens all accordions, filters out what you type in the text field and closes all if there is no text - exactly what i aimed for.

Thanks a lot @Tatu Lund !